# Flutter/Dart: List devices on local network

Tags: networking, dart, flutter

I would like to connect to a computer on the local network from a flutter app. Is there any way to get all machines connected to the local network? Like pinging broadcast address?

Comment: If you're on wifi you should be able to access the desired machine from its local IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this library only works on Android, but...

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mdns

1. Setup mdns for whatever service you're running.
2. Discover the service as such

   ```
   startMdnsDiscovery(String serviceType){

       Mdns mdns = new Mdns(discoveryCallbacks: discoveryCallbacks);

       mdns.startDiscovery(serviceType);

   }
   ```

**UPDATE Mar 26, 2020** - This no longer works with the newest versions of flutter, see below for an updated example.

Updated example: [here](https://github.com/terrabythia/flutter_mdns_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Also, [what is MDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).

Answer (score 8):

To discover your local network and list connected computers, printers and other network devices use [ping_discover_network](https://pub.dev/packages/ping_discover_network) package.

Get local ip and discover network devices:

```
import 'package:wifi/wifi.dart';
import 'package:ping_discover_network/ping_discover_network.dart';

final String ip = await Wifi.ip;
final String subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf('.'));
final int port = 80;

final stream = NetworkAnalyzer.discover(subnet, port);
stream.listen((NetworkAddress addr) {
  if (addr.exists) {
    print('Found device: ${addr.ip}');
  }
});
```

Comment: In my case it return a single ip, while there are 9 devices connected right now.

Comment: @Avnishkumar That is because port (80) may not be opened on devices. This above method works only if the port is known, and open for socket connection in all devices.